# Run JavaScript when title-tooltip is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page with HTML anchor tags that have the title attribute set.

```
<a href="...." title="Some tooltip text" />
```

I want to detect when the tooltip is shown, and run some javascript. This is to log that the tooltip has been displayed. Using OnMouseOver isn't enough since it triggers too early.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's no way to detect when the tooltip is shown. The only workaround I can think of, apart from using your own tooltip library, is to use an `onmouseover` event that triggers a timer (and stops that timer `onmouseout`). But that way, you can never be sure whether the tooltip was actually displayed or not.

Comment: Well that brings up a good point marcel - how _long_ the tooltip was open. @Frode - you could track the time between display and hide of the custom tooltip to make sure it wasn't just a second or two if need be, ya?

Comment: @Dan – I can read short texts within two seconds. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mine would be to create your own [tooltips](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html) that you could append extra 'tracking' to determine if they were displayed or not.

With that library, you could make your own [effect](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html#effects) that does customized things on the over/out of the tooltip.

Comment: Links are all dead.

Answer (score -1):

Use JQuery. If you do sth only particular tags you must set your tags id and/or name attributes.

```
<a href=".." id="x"></a>
```

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {           

           $("#x").mouseenter(function () {
               alert("yeah");
           });

       });
```

If you run javascript code for all `<a>` tags you use this like below.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


           $("a").mouseenter(function () {
               alert("yeah");
           });

       });
```

You add this between `<head>` tags of your page to use JQuery library

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: "Using OnMouseOver isn't enough since it triggers too early." is what the OP had already said.

Comment: "Use jQuery" will work 99.99% of the times as an answer. This is one of 0.01% questions.